# Spacing Out Material UI Typography Components on a Toolbar Component

Tags: material-ui

I'm new to material ui and cannot figure out how to space out Typography components on a Toolbar. I made a short video showing my issue: https://www.useloom.com/share/f2c391c010c142b4b659d805afe8c825

Anyone know how to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Please include the relevant code in your question. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for more details.

Answer (score 6):

Easiest way:

```
<Toolbar>
  <Typography style={{ marginRight: 16 }}>Home</Typography>
  <Typography style={{ marginRight: 16 }}>About</Typography>
  <Typography style={{ marginRight: 16 }}>Hire</Typography>
</Toolbar>
```

Answer (score 4):

In addition to [Marson Mao's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53921279/7477670), I found two other ways to solve this problem.

The first is to use CSS in JS and add a class -- as follows:

```
const styles = {

  grow: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
  menuText: {
    marginRight: 18
  }

};

<Typography variant="button" color="inherit" className={classes.menuText}>Home</Typography>

<Typography variant="button" color="inherit" className={classes.menuText}>About </Typography>

<Typography variant="button" color="inherit" className={classes.menuText}>Hire Me</Typography>
```

The second option is to use the Button component instead of the Typography component -- as follows:

```
<Button variant="text" color="inherit">Home</Button>

<Button variant="text" color="inherit">About </Button>

<Button variant="text" color="inherit">Hire Me</Button>
```

Comment: Nice that you could find alternative answer :) The jss way is the recommended one in `material-ui`, it's great that you can utilize it.